# solution of exponential equation $2^x = x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(1) Real solution of exponential equation $2^x = x$.

(2) Real solution of exponential equation $2^x = x+1$.

$\bf{My\; Try}::$(1) Let $f(x) = 2^x-x$ Then $f^{'}(x) = 2^x\ln(2)-1$ and $f^{''}(x) = 2^x\left(\ln(2)\right)^2>0\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Means $f(x)$ is concave upwards for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Now How can i find real solution of $f(x) = 0$

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: *Hint:* as the function $2^x$ is **convex** for all $x$, it can meet a straight line at most at two points.

Answer (score 2):

For (1) Observe the two equations $y = 2^x$ and $y = x$. Do they intersect at all?

For (2) Do the same thing as with (1). Now, you should notice they intersect. How many points do you think they will intersect?

Answer (score 2):

These sorts of [transcendental equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) are solvable in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). A similar [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1), $2^x=ax$, can be found in the article itself, so in the following I will give only the solution to $2^x=x+1$. Bear in mind that $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ . $$2^x=x+1\quad|\cdot2\quad\iff\quad2^{x+1}=2\,(x+1)\quad|\cdot2^{-(x+1)}\quad\iff\quad1=2\,(x+1)\cdot2^{-(x+1)}$$ $$\frac12=(x+1)\cdot e^{-(x+1)\ln2}\quad|\cdot(-\ln2)\quad\iff\quad-\frac{\ln2}2=-(x+1)\ln2\cdot e^{-(x+1)\ln2}$$ $$-(x+1)\ln2=W\left(-\frac{\ln2}2\right)\qquad\iff\qquad x=-1-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln2}2\right)}{\ln2}$$

Answer (score 1):

When $x\le0$ we know that $0<2^x$. Thus $x<2^x$ when $x\le0$.

When $x>0$ consider the derivatives of both functions. Since $2^x=1$ when $x=0$ and since $$\frac{d}{dx}x<\frac{d}{dx}2^x,\forall x>0$$ we know that $x<2^x,\forall x>0$.

Therefore $x<2^x, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and so there is no solution. You can use a similar method for 2) to show that there is only 1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

$2^x = x$ has no real no solutions. To see this. Suppose there is $a \neq 1, -1$ real such that $f(a) = 2^a - a = 0$ then $a \ln 2 = \ln a \implies \frac{\ln a }{a} = \ln 2 $ So

$$ 2 = e^{\frac{\ln a}{a} } \notin \mathbb{N}$$

contradiction

Comment: How do you know that $e^{\frac{\ln a}a}$ cannot be an integer? (By the way, this is false, since $a=1$ is a counterexample.)

Comment: (It is not clear. It indeed happens that the equation $2=e^{\frac{\ln a}a}$ has no real solutions, but an argument is needed, for example, because $\frac{\ln a}a\le 1/e<\ln 2$.)